# Conditional formatting of cells and emailing

Tags: python

We have made a script in python for auto login to Linux servers and prepare data and daily basis.

We are reading `nds_error` file and preparing a table. My requirement is to make a condition that if any cell in the table doesn't contain the string "Ok", then it will be highlighted with color.

```
f = open('/home/nds_error')
lines = f.readlines()
count=len(lines)
f.close()

body1="""

"""

z=0

while (z<count):
  test = lines[z]
  hello = test.split('|')
  a = hello[0:1]
  a1 = a[0]
  b = hello[1:2]
  b1 = b[0]
  c = hello[2:3]
  c1 = c[0]
  d = hello[3:4]
  d1 = d[0]
  e = hello[4:5]
  e1 = e[0]
  f = hello[5:6]
  f1 = f[0]
  g = hello[6:7]
  g1 = g[0]

  body1 = body1 + '<tr><td style="font-family:Calibri;"><b>' + a1 + '</b></td><td style="font-family:Calibri;">' + b1 + '</td></td><td style="font-family:Calibri;">' + c1 + '</td></td><td style="font-family:Calibri;">' + d1 + '</td></td><td style="font-family:Calibri;">' + e1 + '</td></td><td style="font-family:Calibri;">' + f1 + '</td></td><td style="font-family:Calibri;">' + g1 + '</td></tr>'
  z=z+1

start1="""

<table border="3">
<tr style="font-family:Bell MT;font-size:120%;color:#360E9B">
<caption><b>One-NDS Nodes</b></caption>
  <th style="font-family:Bell MT;font-    size:92%;color:#360E9B;">PGD/RDS/BDS</th>

<table border="3">
<tr style="font-family:Bell MT;font-size:120%;color:#360E9B">    
<caption><b>One-NDS Nodes</b></caption>
  <th style="font-family:Bell MT;font-    size:92%;color:#360E9B;">PGD/RDS/BDS</th>


  <th style="font-family:Bell MT;font-size:92%;color:#360E9B;">Disk Space Utilization > 40%</th>
 <th style="font-family:Bell MT;font-size:92%;color:#360E9B;">CPU Load > 40%</th>
 <th style="font-family:Bell MT;font-size:92%;color:#360E9B;">Link status with other DS Node</th>
 <th style="font-family:Bell MT;font-size:92%;color:#360E9B;">DS nodes SYNC status</th>
 <th style="font-family:Bell MT;font-size:92%;color:#360E9B;">DS Load stats (0 rejects)</th>
 <th style="font-family:Bell MT;font-size:92%;color:#360E9B;">Backup</th>
</tr>

"""

end1 = """
</table>
<br>
"""
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Hi, My requirement is to make a condition that if any cell in the table is not containing the string "Ok", then it will be highlighted with color. table is formed from file named "nds_error" which looks like below.
hlrapr101|Ok|Ok|Ok
Kindly help.

Comment: That's your requirement, but it is not a question. You need to have a very specific question for this to be a fit for SO (and "how do I do it?" is not appropriate)

Comment: How do i do conditional font changes for a cell/text through Python?

Comment: Using `if`(and maybe `else`)? I'm not sure what else you could possibly mean. (Also somewhat unrelatd I really think that using a templating engine such as [**Jinja2**](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) would make your life and code much simpler)